# xcopy /d copy all files every time, even unchanged files

Tags: backup, xcopy

i try this command line

```
xcopy e:\myfolder /EXCLUDE:excludeList.txt \\192.168.158.15\public\comp\myfolder /E/I/D/R/H/Y
```

the command copy all files every time even unchanged files 
i use /d that suppose to copy just newer files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a small test shows it does work. you must have other problem ...

[image]

### edit

in `netwoek` enviroment - you should add `/z`

[image]

Comment: maybe it's because i'm copying to in network and not to same computer?